# How to enable Back Button on Viewcontroller after TabBarcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, tabbarcontroller

I am unable to enable back button on `HomeViewController` and `MapViewController`. I do have a Splash Screen before `TabBarContoller` which is the initial `ViewController`. Everything is working fine except the back button on `HomeViewController` and `MapViewController`. Please help me to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: They are root view controllers for navigation controller.They won't have back button.Did you mean you are not seeing back button after pushing viewcontrollers on them?...

Comment: yes. I am unable to see back button after pushViewControllers on them

Answer (score 0):

You can't show `back` button on your `rootViewcontroller` of `NavigationController`.

Here `map` or `home` are rootViewControllers for your navigation controllers so you can't see back button on that controller. If you will push anothe viewcontroller on that I mean on map or home then on that controller you will find back button.

And if your home or map Viewcontroller have back button and after clicking on that on which viewcontroller you will go?

So it is normal behaviour according to your screenshot shows in question.